# Kivy force at least one checkbox

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, kivy

## Background

I've grouped 2 CheckBoxes in Kivy using `group: 'my-group'`.

## The problem

If I click on the selected CheckBox, it turns off and no option is selected. Both CheckBoxes are turned off.

## My question

How can I force at least one of the CheckBoxes to be active?

Answer (score 8):

Found it!

```
allow_no_selection: False
```

Comment: Docs here for anyone else wondering: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.ToggleButtonBehavior.allow_no_selection